# Is there a framework to cache HTML pages on iOS? 

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, uiwebview

I'm looking to cache HTML pages inside an application that uses UIWebView.

Is there a framework that will allow me to do this and if not what method would you recommend?

On the server side these files are being seen as PHP so I'd just be caching whatever the file gives back out.

Comment: A clever caching framework is HJCache: http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/  (it's an image-oriented framework, but it works with any object, including html pages).

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used RNCachingURLProtocol , a way to do drop-in offline caching for UIWebView

Reference:
http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.